# Will Application pause during minor GC in java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Will the whole application stop serving the requests during Minor GC execution?
I am able to configure GC paramaters for my application. Can you please help me in understanding below GC log format. 
[image]

```
2015-03-30T10:51:08.157-0400: 25.583: [GC [PSYoungGen: 1572864K->198625K(1835008K)] 1670953K->296714K(6029312K), 0.4902390 secs] [Times: user=1.56 sys=0.21, real=0.50 secs]
2015-03-30T10:51:50.081-0400: 67.507: [GC [PSYoungGen: 1834989K->262142K(1419264K)] 2105157K->613533K(5613568K), 0.1827340 secs] [Times: user=2.93 sys=0.15, real=0.19 secs]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the whole application stop serving the requests during Minor GC execution?

Yes, AFAIK every collector (apart from some commercial, expensive implementations perhaps) will stop the world for GC collection. It won't necessarily stop the world for the entirety of its pass, but it will contain a stop the world segment. *(At least this used to be the case - happy to be proven wrong!)* This is rarely a problem in practice however, the request won't be refused, it will (in its worst case) just take a bit longer while waiting for GC.

Unless you're placing a lot of load on the GC or it's badly tuned, this is unlikely to be an issue in practice.

> Can you please help me in understanding below GC log format.

It shows you are using the parallel scavenge collector, and that two collections occurred, taking 0.5 and 0.19 seconds.